# both method put in class ContentValues of type

Tags: android, scala

A part of Scala-Android application:

```
val contentValues = new ContentValues()
val value: Long = 123
contentValues.put("key", value)
```

It throws an exception:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[ant:scalac] both method put in class ContentValues of type (x$1: String, x$2: Double)Unit
[ant:scalac] and  method put in class ContentValues of type (x$1: String, x$2: Float)Unit
```

What does it have to do with Double and Float if there **is** `put(String, Long): Unit` in Android library which must be used here? Why isn't it being applying here?

Comment: The Scala `Long` is different from `java.lang.Long`. Try to declare your `value` explicitly as `java.lang.Long`.

Comment: @Beryllium, are you sure? I though it was `type Long = java.lang.Long` which is exactly the synonym for Java long.

Comment: Beryllium is right. Java Long is automatically boxed to Scala one, but not the reverse (Java doesn't box convert Scala Long). There you explicitly declare a Scala Long. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Long